# OwlCarousel Thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

So I created an image carousel and then another carousel for its thumbnails since the thumbnails are different images from the ones in the carousel. Now my problem is when trying to make the images change by clicking the thumbnails.

For the thumbnail function I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/gijsroge/OwlCarousel2-Thumbs

Here's my setup :

```
<div class="owl-carousel main-carousel" data-slider-id="1">
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
    <div>Your Content</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-thumbs owl-carousel" data-slider-id="1">
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 1</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 2</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 3</button>
    <button class="owl-thumb-item">slide 4</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is linked here: https://codepen.io/olgaysezgin/pen/JBdrxE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({

    items: 1,


  });
});


// the following to the end is whats needed for the thumbnails.
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


  // 1) ASSIGN EACH 'DOT' A NUMBER
  dotcount = 1;

  jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('dotnumber' + dotcount);
    jQuery(this).attr('data-info', dotcount);
    dotcount = dotcount + 1;
  });

  // 2) ASSIGN EACH 'SLIDE' A NUMBER
  slidecount = 1;

  jQuery('.owl-item').not('.cloned').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('slidenumber' + slidecount);
    slidecount = slidecount + 1;
  });

  // SYNC THE SLIDE NUMBER IMG TO ITS DOT COUNTERPART (E.G SLIDE 1 IMG TO DOT 1 BACKGROUND-IMAGE)
  jQuery('.owl-dot').each(function() {

    grab = jQuery(this).data('info');

    slidegrab = jQuery('.slidenumber' + grab + ' img').attr('src');
    console.log(slidegrab);

    jQuery(this).css("background-image", "url(" + slidegrab + ")");

  });

  // THIS FINAL BIT CAN BE REMOVED AND OVERRIDEN WITH YOUR OWN CSS OR FUNCTION, I JUST HAVE IT
  // TO MAKE IT ALL NEAT 
  amount = jQuery('.owl-dot').length;
  gotowidth = 100 / amount;

  jQuery('.owl-dot').css("width", gotowidth + "%");
  newwidth = jQuery('.owl-dot').width();
  jQuery('.owl-dot').css("height", newwidth + "px");



});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-cont {
  width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.owl-carouse div {
  width: 100%;
}


/*SEE END OF THUMBNAIL FUCNTION TO TINKER SIZE OF THUMBS*/

.owl-carousel .owl-controls .owl-dot {
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* BELOW THIS IS JUST MY OWN BACKGROUND ETC AND ISN'T NEEDED */

body {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#1f1f1f, #000000);
  background: radial-gradient(#1f1f1f, #000000);
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  background: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  z-index: 200;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-dot {
  float: left;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <!-- STYLE FOR H1 TAG -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!-- ESSENTIAL OWL CARO CSS FILE -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.1.6/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
</head>

<h1>Owl Carousel 2 Thumbnails</h1>


<div class="slide-cont">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav1-1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav2-1.png"></div>
    <div><img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav3-1.png"></div>
    <div> <img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav4-1.png"></div>
    <div> <img src="http://imew.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/cav4-1.png"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--
Copyright (c) 2018 by Olgay Sezgin (https://codepen.io/olgaysezgin/pen/JBdrxE)
Fork of an original work by Martin Whitaker (https://codepen.io/sirnightowl/pen/JoJwrE)

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
-->
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll implemment this and let you know how it goes.